# C# Generate Nested Dictionaries from the a List

Tags: c#

I managed to pull the following data from the database into a `List<>` using Entity Framework.

```
id      Variable        Value   Coef
--------------------------------------
1000    Gender          Male     0
1001    Gender          Female  -0.205
1009    College Code    AT      -1.732
1010    College Code    BU      -1.806
1011    College Code    EH      -1.728
1012    College Code    EN      -2.003
1013    College Code    LF      -1.779
1014    College Code    pp      -2.042
1015    College Code    SC      -2.070
1016    College Code    UC      -1.845
1017    AGI             AGI N/A  0.236
1018    AGI             0       -0.684
```

I am a bit new to C#, so I wanted to know what would be the best way to create a nested `Dictionary` with the following format:

```
//to construct a dictionary to hold Dictionary<Variable, {Value, Coef}>
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> data = Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();
```

So, for instance, I could access the data like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(data['Gender']['Male']) //returns 0
Console.WriteLine(data['College Code']['LF']) //returns -1.779
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be simpler if you combined those values into one key like `data["College Code=LF"]`. If you can't do that then you need a custom type for the first lookup with its own string indexer that returns a `IDictionary<string,decimal>` implementation.

Comment: @JohnWu I have tried to do it with nested foreach loop but I ended up with nonsensical result. Basically I got stuck.

Comment: @Igor That is a good idea. I will try that but will check back.

Comment: Shouldn't `data["Gender"]["Male"]` return 0?

Comment: @juharr my question is how to construct it not how to access it. I used Igor's suggestions and it seems to be working(thanks to Igor). but It would be great if we could come up with an algorithm to construct it.

Comment: @jax I was pointing out that your data has 0 for the Gender Male row, not -0.205 which is what your question says you'd expect for those keys.

Comment: @juharr you are correct on that. it was a typo I edited it and now it's fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = _dbContext.Tbl.ToDictionary(_ => _.Variable + "=" + _.Value, _ => _.Coef, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

With the data you have shown there is no need to group, just create your composite key and specify the value. I also recommend using a case insensitive key.

You would then access the data this way where `College Code=LF` is the key.

```
Console.WriteLine(data["College Code=LF"]);
```

Comment: great solution. I used foreach to do the same but this one is more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Using some initial data as follows

```
public class data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Variable { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public decimal Coef { get; set; }
}

var listy = new List<data>() {
    new data() { id=1000, Variable="Gender", Value="Male", Coef=0m },
    new data() { id=1001, Variable="Gender", Value="Female", Coef=-0.205m },
    new data() { id=1009, Variable="College Code", Value="AT", Coef=-1.732m },
    new data() { id=1010, Variable="College Code", Value="BU", Coef=-1.806m },
    new data() { id=1011, Variable="College Code", Value="EH", Coef=-1.728m },
    new data() { id=1012, Variable="College Code", Value="EN", Coef=-2.003m },
    new data() { id=1013, Variable="College Code", Value="LF", Coef=-1.779m },
    new data() { id=1014, Variable="College Code", Value="pp", Coef=-2.042m },
    new data() { id=1015, Variable="College Code", Value="SC", Coef=-2.070m },
    new data() { id=1016, Variable="College Code", Value="UC", Coef=-1.845m },
    new data() { id=1017, Variable="AGI", Value="AGI N/A", Coef=0.236m },
    new data() { id=1018, Variable="AGI", Value="0", Coef=-0.684m },
};
```

Get the distinct list of Variable fields to seed the outer dictionary, then find related items in the data source, and create an inner dictionary for those:

```
var b = listy
    .Select(x => x.Variable)
    .Distinct()
    // outer dictionary, key is Variable
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => 
        listy
        // find items in the list with the same Variable
        .Where(x => x.Variable == v)
        // and create a dictionary for the Value/Coef pairs.
        .ToDictionary(k2 => k2.Value, v2 => v2.Coef));
```

Some interactive shell output:

```
> b["AGI"]
Dictionary<string, decimal>(2) { { "AGI N/A", 0.236 }, { "0", -0.684 } }
> b["AGI"]["0"]
-0.684
> b["College Code"]["AT"]
-1.732
> b["College Code"]["BU"]
-1.806
```

Comment: This is going to iterate the list twice which is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Given a collection of the date you should be able to get the results you want like this.

```
var lookup = data.GroupBy(x => x.Variable)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.ToDictionary(y => y.Value, y => y.Coef));
```

Note this will fail if you have multiple items with the same values in the `Variable` and `Value` columns.

Comment: I do have multiple values in the `Variable` but not `Value`. That is why I want `Variable' to be the key for its sub dictionary items.